# Нужна помощь с кодом php

Tags: php

только начал изучать Php, дали задание которое не могу выполнить второй день и по сему прошу помощи опытных программистов...
Такое вот задание :
Создать форму, которая будет содержать следующие поля (строка name, строка surname, число age) и кнопка для отправки формы, При нажатии на данную кнопку должно появляться сообщения в котором будут указанны введенная фамилия,имя и возраст...
все сделал, вот только не пойму как сделать что бы выводило фамилию , имя и возраст..
вот что получилось у меня :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где тут пхп? Если таки пхп, то форма должна отправится на сервер, а вы это зачем-то запретили. Ну и основы html стоит прочитать, у вас в форме нет ни одного имени поля

Comment: И, кстати, код надо вставлять текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно.

Comment: Что самостоятельно согласен, но на лекции была только теория не относящееся к заданию, есле бы помогли я бы хоть как то для себя код разобрал...

Comment: это результат за 2 дня? ну такое се... в гугле запрос: пхп работа с формами - и будет счастье, разбирайтесь - это базовые вещи...

Comment: У вас тут вообще ни строчки php-кода. Поизучайте ещё недельку-другую, почитайте учебники, узнайте что такое php хотя бы

Comment: изучаю, просто медленно очень... а работу сдавать уже завтра, вот и обратился за помощью, в гугле нечего не нашел...

Comment: Хотябы по гугли php формы отправки данных мли что то типо того. А то что ты html пишешь в php файле это еще не php код )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['done'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? $email = $_POST['email'] : $email = 'Invalid email';
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    echo "<script>alert('Name: $name, Email: $email , Age: $age')</script>";
}
?>
```

```html
<style>
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        width: 300px;
    }

    li {
        padding: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    label {
        float: left;
    }

    input {
        float: right;
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
        float: none;
    }
</style>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="number" name="age">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="done">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: @Levit_86 Если не сложно то пометьте ответ лучшим и полезным)

Comment: не вопрос, куда жать? не вижу..

Comment: @Levit_86 https://imgur.com/a/zg80noC